# PHP function written in 5.5 throws error when upgraded to 7.0

Tags: syntax-error, global, php-7

here is the function that worked prior to upgrading to 7.0

```
function set_session_vars() {
$nb_args=func_num_args();
$arg_list=func_get_args();
for($i=0;$i<$nb_args;$i++) {
    global $$arg_list[$i];
    $_SESSION[$arg_list[$i]] = $$arg_list[$i];
}
```

}

now it causer error that says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/mvyc1956/public_html/members/includes/functions.php on line 322
```

I believe its related to non backward compatable changes to GLOBAL  and the use of $$ and arrays, but my PHP is not good enough to figure it out.

Is there someone who is familiar with why this line :

```
global $$arg_list[$i];
```

which is line 322 that is being reported as the cause of the error, would be failing now, and what would you recommend I change the code to in order to have it work with PHP 7?

I did some googling and found [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) but again, im not understanding what needs to be changed.

thanks

says syntax error so some of the code in the function is no longer valid, but it would take a php 7 expert to see it.

**UPDATE**
I removed the word GLOBAL from the above code and the app "seems" to be now working fine so I will now ask:

Does anyone know specifically, why Global was the non compatibility issue? and is my fix of simply removing it a solid one or will is there a better practice or will this removal come back to haunt me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Backward incompatible changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php):

> **global only accepts simple variables**
>
> [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) can no longer be used with the global keyword. The curly brace syntax can be used to emulate the previous behaviour if required:

```
// Valid in PHP 5 only.
global $$foo->bar;

// Valid in PHP 5 and 7.
global ${$foo->bar};
```

So in your case it should become:

```
global ${$arg_list[$i]};
```

Comment: Thanks. I literally love you! :-) You made my day! And for that I grant you eternal life! :-)

Comment: here I am 3 years later with the same issued and searched global $$arg_list[$i]; and found this solution AGAIN and it helped me AGAIN, so thanks AGAIN :-)

Answer (score 2):

The global keyword tells PHP to access a global variable (per launch of the script) instead of a local variable (per function).  For example,

```
global $foo;
```

means that future uses of the variable $foo in that function refer to the global variable with that name, rather than a variable within the function itself.

What this is trying to do is look up a variable by arbitrary name in the global namespace.  That's entirely the wrong way to do things.  Instead, you should have a global array and use keys in the array.  In fact, $$ is arguably a bad idea in general.

But that's neither here nor there.  The problem is that the parsing rules changed in PHP 7.0 in a non-backwards-compatible way (because they're using a more traditional parser now, and thus had to make their associativity rules self-consistent).

More details here: 
 http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect

To make a long story short, you need to rewrite that as:

```
global ${$arg_list[$i]};
```

and then your code will work correctly on both PHP 7 and PHP 5.

Incidentally, the function only *appears* to work without the `global` keyword.  In fact, it is always getting empty values for those variables.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification part. I gave you an upvote for it. thanks.